# Don't show the Tour hero header when the user has the Informed badge

Tags: feature-request, help-center

When a user has the [Informed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed) badge, the Tour hero header on the Help Center landing page should not be shown.

So, instead of this:

> [image: screenshot of current page]

I'd like to see this:

> [image: screenshot of desired page]

Comment: They could do something similar with the Documentation header too. I've been using it since private beta, but it still tells me to take the tour...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I am using the chat link placed there quite often.

Comment: That is not hard to solve. All you need to do is use Greasemonkey and have a JavaScript script that removes this header. I use that, by the way.

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas we're all pretty tech-savvy... the point is not to use userscripts, the point is to make stackoverflow a better place

Comment: @jeremy I totally agree. I would definitely want to improve SO in all possible ways. But just there are some things I personally don't like while others like (you can't be good for everybody).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: You could just dismiss the banner :-)

Comment: This will take 6-8 weeks.

Comment: Quick & easy in [stylish](https://userstyles.org): `#herobox.alternate { display: none !important; }`; URL: `http://stackoverflow.com/help` (not that this directly solves your problem).

Comment: @Bergi How? There's no dismiss icon on that header...?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: Oops, I confused it with the blue "*Announcing Stack Overflow Documentation*" banner